# Error while buliding PHP on AIX5.2

Tags: php, aix

I get the following error  message while buliding `PHP` on `AIX5.2`:

```
"checking whether libxml build works... no",
```

and actually I have installed `libxml2` and `libxml2-devel`,

What could be the problem?

Thank you!

(I check the config.log, and the last part of the message says:

configure:21603: checking whether libxml build works
configure:21630: gcc -o conftest -O -xs -xstrconst -zlazyload   -L/opt/freeware/lib -L/opt/freeware/lib conftest.c

```
      -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm 1>&5
```

gcc: unrecognized option '-zlazyload'
gcc: language strconst not recognized
gcc: language strconst not recognized
ld: 0711-715 ERROR: File conftest.c cannot be processed.
        The file must be an object file, an import file, or an archive.
collect2: ld returned 8 exit status
configure: failed program was:

## line 21619 "configure"

## include "confdefs.h"

```
char xmlInitParser();
int main() {
  xmlInitParser();
  return 0;
}
```

)
could some one tell me what happened? 
thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `config.log` for the specific error.  configure just tries to compile a test program using libxml.   If it doesn't compile, it considers that libxml doesn't work.

During ./configure, it should output where its finding libxml's install directory - what does that say?

On my AIX 5.2 box, I have these two installed:

```
libxml2-2.6.21-4
libxml2-devel-2.6.21-4
```

And they live in /usr/opt/freeware/lib/libxml2.a, but there is a symlink in /usr/lib pointing back to the library (includes are done similar)

```
/usr/lib/libxml2.a -> ../../opt/freeware/lib/libxml2.a
```

So configure can find them.   The RPM package should have made the symlinks.  Maybe yours are missing so it can't find the path to libxml?

You could build your own (later) version of libxml, and install that somewhere (usually /usr/local).  The prebuilt RPM is pretty outdated anyways.

You can also use `--with-libxml-dir=<path>` to point to the install dir directly.   `--with-libxml-dir=/opt/freeware/` should work.

Comment: Yes, I just install libxml2-2.7.7 and libxml2-devel-2.7.7 and add the information "--with-libxml-dir=/opt/freeware/", but still it can't work.

Comment: Check your config.log file.   It will output what the compiler is dumping and why it won't compile.  Just break configure right after that line comes up and see whats in your log...  I'm guessing its obvious...

Comment: configure:21603: checking whether libxml build works
configure:21630: gcc -o conftest -O -xs -xstrconst -zlazyload   -L/opt/freeware/lib -L/opt/freeware/lib conftest.c

          -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm 1>&5

Comment: go with above one:
gcc: unrecognized option '-zlazyload'
gcc: language strconst not recognized
gcc: language strconst not recognized
ld: 0711-715 ERROR: File conftest.c cannot be processed.
        The file must be an object file, an import file, or an archive.
collect2: ld returned 8 exit status
configure: failed program was:
#line 21619 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"


    char xmlInitParser();
    int main() {
      xmlInitParser();
      return 0;
    }